# Vuex Getters doesn't call state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I trying to return back sorted data (which is the already defined state) in a list with the help of a getter, then assign it to the `html` list in my `vue`, but it seems it's empty when I check with the `vuex` tools.

I don't know what am doing wrong.

Below is my `store.js` file

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state:{
    displayChatMessages: [],
  },
  mutations:{
    create(state, payload) {

      state.displayChatMessages.push(payload)
    },
    reset(state){
      state.displayChatMessages = []
    },
  },
  actions :{

    getAllData:({commit}, payload) => {
      commit('create',payload)
    },
  },
  getters:{
    filteredChatMessages: state => (chatID) => {
      return state.displayChatMessages[0]
        .filter(el => el.groupid === chatID).sort((l,r)=> l.timestamp - r.timestamp)
    },
  },
}
```

Then, after, I call it in the `computed` area like below :

```
  ...mapGetters('chatMessages',['filteredChatMessages']),
```

Then , I call the Getter inside my function , like below :

```
 getFilteredMessages: function() {
      let vm = this
      return vm.filteredChatMessages(vm.groupID)
    },
```

Then afterwards, then I set the getFilteredMessages() to the list , getFilteredMessages() , is also defined in the `computed` section.

But when I look into my `vuex tools` , I don't see it as an array :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `return vm.filteredChatMessages(groupID)`. Where is `groupID` coming from? Should it be `this.groupID`?

Comment: ` ...mapGetters('chatMessages'['filteredChatMessages']),`. I think there is an missing comma after chatMessages. and @skirtle is right groupID is missing

Comment: Are you sure you want `return state.displayChatMessages[0]...` and not `return state.displayChatMessages...`

Comment: @skirtle, `vm` is `this` , don't worry about it, sorry for posting it, and the group ID is `this.groupID`

Comment: @bgul, I have added the comma , had made a mistake copying it. But it was there initially.

Comment: @paul, yes , even when I decide to return only `return state.displayChatMessages` in the `getter`, the getter doesn't return anything , I tested all that. I don't what am missing , the image I provided is what it shows in the `vuex` tools